# Wordpress Template - sidebar jumps upon scrolling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having an issue that I can't find the cause of - I didn't see any questions here that were even close - which is a first!

I'm developing a client site via a customized wordpress template. I have a sidebar that uses three 'text' widgets. When you first load the page, the layout is perfect, but as soon as you interact with the page - i.e. scroll down - the entire sidebar jumps 20-30 pixels to the right.

Anyone have any idea where I should begin looking for the cause? I'd really appreciate some pointers!

Dev site URL: http://dev.familyandnursingcare.com.php53-6.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com
I copied the various template css files here for viewing: http://www.bluetabby.net/fnc/

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script.js has these below lines which sets a class 'fixed' to the sidebar on window scroll event

```
 $window.scroll(function(event) {
     $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
     scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
     topPosition = Math.max(0, (sidebarTop) - scrollTop),
     topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
     $sidebar.css('top', topPosition + $addHeigth);
 });
```

in CSS

```
.sidebar.right.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 725px;
}
```

You need to change margin-left: 725px to around 690px to make it same as layout on load.

Comment: Question: so I could just call another class then? and not have the sidebar be fixed at all? that would be my preference. I'm pretty new to trying to work within WP templates. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need a fixed sidebar then remove the scroll event in JS which is adding the class and also remove the class from CSS

Comment: Genius! Thank you SO much! I never would have thought to look through my js, I assumed it was solely a CSS problem.